# Auto Sign In with JS

Tags: javascript, autologin

I would like to create button "Sign In" on my WebSite, to the assigned button will be a script with variable login and password.

When I click the button "Sign In", the script will redirect to this website: https://login.umk.pl/login and fill in the fields ID and Password and will auto-login. Is it possible in JS?

My script:

```
function zal(){
    var login = "LOGIN";
    var pass = "PASSWORD";
    alert("Login: " + login + "Password: " + pass);
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a user to fill in his/her login details on your website and then the user gets redirected to that other website where his/her login details gets filled in?

Comment: it's only possible if the remote site accepts the username and password as querystring parameters and its code fills the fields for you (but would you want your password in the querystring? I doubt it, so it's unlikely) , and even if that was possible I doubt it would automatically log in. Otherwise it would be a security risk on that site to allow you to inject any script into the page which would do it. What are you actually trying to achieve here, and why? Sounds like a strange requirement.

Comment: I would like to show how in simple easy way capture login and password in the lecture.